# How to export blob data values with IBExpert/ IBEscript?

Tags: blob, export-to-csv, ibexpert

I want to export data from my database to a csv file using IBEscript for a Firebird database. Everything works fine just the columns with blob data don't work. they just miss within the csv file.

When I run the same query in the IBexpert and export the data to csv I check the box "export text blob values" and the data is included. How can I use this option with the script as well?

I need the script since I want an automatic export using the task planer.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

csv format with blobs makes no sense,since any delimiter (tab,semikolon, etc) can be part of the blob and will destroy your structure.

but automated import/export also with blobs is no real problem in scripts (ibeblock is not available in personal edition)

```
http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.InsertingFileDataIntoADatabase

http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.IbecLoadFromFile

http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.IbecSaveToFile
```

Holger
www.ibexpert.com